# $r^2$ using Robust Regression

Tags: regression, r-squared, robust

I am interested in measure of quality of robust regression.

How should I calculate it? It is clear that $r^2$ of robust regression should be smaller than $r^2$ OLS regression. Even if OLS is totally wrong and robust is right.

The question is: which feature from the set is the best predictor for the response, using robust regression as a predictive model? I know that there are several clear outliers (leverage and "out-of-prediction-interval" points).

The types of regression that I'm interested in: 1) regression that uses loss function (such as MM or M), 2) median regression (Theil-Sen).

Comment: Exactly how you are doing "robust regression" is relevant, because many forms of this use a specific loss function which would be natural to use to assess the quality.  Could you edit your question to provide this information?

Comment: I am interested in general (just an idea how to construct something similar to $r^2$), but I typically use rlm from MASS (MM method) or Theil-Sen. I guess the answer will be different for these types.

Comment: @whuber since I use simple linear models with only one predictor I used this paper: http://www.stat.tugraz.at/AJS/ausg111+2/111+2Shevlyakov.pdf , but these correlation measures are not connected with any regression type (as far I know)

Comment: A simple measure is the plug in one: just compute the weighted $r^2$ where the weights are those coming from your fitting routine. MM definitely returns this vector of weight. Not sure about T-S but it's modern counterpart (FLTS) does.